# MySql GROUPBY value Based on data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have a query which returns the following dataset ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTRtM.png)) :

```
+ ------------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------------------ + ------------------- + --------- + ----------------------- + ---------------------- + ----------------- +
| col_0_0_      | col_1_0_ | col_2_0_   | col_3_0_                 | col_4_0_            | col_5_0_  | col_6_0_                | col_7_0_               | col_8_0_          |
+ ------------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------------------ + ------------------- + --------- + ----------------------- + ---------------------- + ----------------- +
| LAI-100003662 | dsa      | 4546576766 | dfdfdfd2@lendingkart.com | 2015-11-30 02:30:11 | Sultanpur | Incomplete Applications | Application Incomplete | Documents Pending |
| LAI-100003662 | dsa      | 4546576766 | dfdfdfd2@lendingkart.com | 2015-11-30 02:30:11 | Sultanpur | Incomplete Applications | Null                   | Null              |
+ ------------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------------------ + ------------------- + --------- + ----------------------- + ---------------------- + ----------------- +
```

Now when I apply a **GROUPBY col_0_0**, on the query which results this dataset, I get only only one row which is ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH2Q4.png)):

```
+ ------------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------------------ + ------------------- + --------- + ----------------------- + ---------------------- + ----------------- +
| col_0_0_      | col_1_0_ | col_2_0_   | col_3_0_                 | col_4_0_            | col_5_0_  | col_6_0_                | col_7_0_               | col_8_0_          |
+ ------------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------------------ + ------------------- + --------- + ----------------------- + ---------------------- + ----------------- +
| LAI-100003662 | dsa      | 4546576766 | dfdfdfd2@lendingkart.com | 2015-11-30 02:30:11 | Sultanpur | Incomplete Applications | Application Incomplete | Documents Pending |
+ ------------- + -------- + ---------- + ------------------------ + ------------------- + --------- + ----------------------- + ---------------------- + ----------------- +
```

1) Why does `GROUP BY` only give me the first row and not the second row from the original dataset?

2) How does `GROUP BY` actually work in this scenario?

SQL QUERY with GROUP BY :

```
select  loan0_.col_0_0_,
        loan0_.col_1_0_,
        loan0_.col_2_0_,
        loan0_.col_3_0_,
        loan0_.col_4_0_, 
        loan0_.col_5_0_,
        dsastatus2_.col_6_0_,
        dsastatus2_.col_7_0_, 
        dsastatus2_.col_8_0_ 
    FROM loan0_
    cross join  user1_
    cross join dsastatus2_ 
    where loan0_.L_USER_ID=user1_.U_GUID
        and loan0_.L_LEADSOURCE='DSA'
        and (loan0_.L_SUB_STATUS_ID=dsastatus2_.ADMIN_STATUS_ID
            or loan0_.L_STATUS_ID=dsastatus2_.ADMIN_STATUS_ID)
        and user1_.U_REFID='dsa001'
        and (loan0_.L_APPLICATION_ID like 'LAI-100003662')
    GROUP BY col_0_0_ ;
```

Comment: show  your sql code please  .. the img mean nothings without code

Comment: Read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) "In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate"

Comment: `MySQL` for some God-forsaken reason allows you to add `GROUP BY` to your query without specifying all of the non-aggregated columns.  When you do this, it *arbitrarily* picks records to return.  So to answer your second question: it doesn't.  But to answer your first question, `GROUP BY` (for lack of a better explanation...) groups the resultset by the values provided.  Since the two records have the same value for `col_0_0`, they are grouped together.  This should only ever be done with aggregates.  A `GROUP BY` without an aggregate really doesn't make much sense for what the result would be

Answer (score 0):

To answer the questions directly::

**1) Why does GROUP BY only give me the first row and not the second row from the original dataset?**
Because that's the way the MSQL engine works.  Read the docs.  "the server is free to choose any value from each group (not in the group by), so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate"

**2) How does GROUP BY actually work in this scenario?**
See above

MySQL extended Group by direct quote from docs:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers.

MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)

If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, **the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate**, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which value within each group the server chooses. Disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see only one line is because this is what GROUP BY does -- it combines records with the same values into one.  In this case the value is LAI-1000...3662 is the one value.

Now on most SQL systems if you include columns that are not in the group by or aggregate function it will give you an error but on mysql it just gives you a random value from the other column's possibilities.